# Почему в сниппете отображается не то, что указано в мета-теге description?

Tags: теги, сниппет

Ситуация: когда даю ссылку на наш сайт, например в телеге, под названием в сниппете приводится текст, который у нас указан в html в public. title и description у нас меняются на разных страницах, в инспекторе видно что всё работает, но даю ссылку - и отображается то, что захардкорено в public, динамически меняющееся описание не учитывается.

[image: Вот код на сайте - description правильный]

[image: А вот что появляется, когда мы вставляем ссылку в телегу - не то, что в descrition]

Comment: Я пока ещё стажёр, много не знаю. Роясь по интернету с этой проблемой, натолкнулся на многократные упоминания метатегов Open Graph. Кажется, начинаю понимать что у нас не так. Чтобы всякие соцсети видели заголовки и описания конкретных страниц, надо их прописывать в метатегах Open Graph, а не как у нас сделано.